# Using this.setAttribute in an Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently trying to use this.setAttribute in an Ajax call but when I try I get the following error:

```
TypeError: this.setAttribute is not a function
```

Here is what my code looks like:

```
proto.toggle = function() {
    var id= this.getAttribute('data-id');
    //var this = $(this); <-- I tried this doesnt work
    $.ajax({
          url: "php/add.php",
          type: 'post',
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {
              e : id
          },
          success: function(response) {
            if(response == "login"){
             //do something
            }else{
              this.setAttribute('active', '');
            }  
          }
    });

  }
}

proto.onClick = function() {
  this.toggle();
}
```

I can set the attribute to 'active' outside of the Ajax but not inside. I tried to set a variable to `$(this)` but I was unable to get that to work either. Are there ways to work around this?

Comment: Use `var that = this` before `$.ajax` and on success `that.setAttribute('active', '');` or better use jQuery `var $this = $(this);` and in success `$this.attr('active', '');`

Comment: Awesome didn't know I had to switch to that.

Comment: With `jQuery.ajax()`, you can also use its `context:` option to specify the value you'd like the callbacks to use. Or, in general, [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the callbacks.